# How to pass data from AWS API Gateway Custom Authorizer to an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using AWS API GAteway's Custom Authorizer to validate an application's token,
I am able to work with the Custom Authorizer properly,
 
ie. able to validate the token and return an IAM policy,
 
Which decides whether to allow the request to be forwarded to a Business logic Lambda function.

I now need to send additional data from the Custom Authorizer to the Business logic Lambda,

**I have so far found out that there are two way's to achieve this -**
1. Stringify data as Principal Id in the Policy to be returned.
2. [Set data in Context object of the policy](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/enhanced-context-for-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/), which can be retrieved as `$context.authorizer.<key>` as per the code

I am trying the 2nd method, but unable to retrieve the data which was set in the context, in the Business logic Lambda.

I am using the NodeJs code from this GitHub Repo -
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/nodejs/index.js

**I am unable to view the default context set the Code -**

```
authResponse.context = {
    key : 'value', // $context.authorizer.key -> value
    number : 1,
    bool: true
};
```

**Following is the Event Object log in the Business Logic Lambda Function -**

```
Event: {
    type: 'REQUEST',
    methodArn: 'someARN',
    resource: 'somePath',
    path: 'somePath',
    httpMethod: 'GET',
    headers: {
        accept: '*/*',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        authorization: 'someToken',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        Host: 'someAPI.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
        partner: 'php',
        'postman-token': 'someToken',
        timestamp: '1555034345',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/someIP Safari/537.36',
        'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-someId',
        'X-Forwarded-For': 'someIP',
        'X-Forwarded-Port': '443',
        'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https'
    },
    multiValueHeaders: {
        accept: ['*/*'],
        'accept-encoding': ['gzip, deflate, br'],
        'accept-language': ['en-US,en;q=0.9'],
        authorization: ['someToken'],
        'cache-control': ['no-cache'],
        'content-type': ['application/json'],
        Host: ['someAPI.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'],
        partner: ['php'],
        'postman-token': ['someToken'],
        timestamp: ['1555034345'],
        'user-agent': ['Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/someIP Safari/537.36'],
        'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': ['Root=1-someId'],
        'X-Forwarded-For': ['someIP'],
        'X-Forwarded-Port': ['443'],
        'X-Forwarded-Proto': ['https']
    },
    queryStringParameters: {
        user_id: '4'
    },
    multiValueQueryStringParameters: {
        user_id: ['4']
    },
    pathParameters: {},
    stageVariables: {
        someVariable: 'someValue',
    },
    requestContext: {
        resourceId: 'someId',
        resourcePath: 'somePath',
        httpMethod: 'GET',
        extendedRequestId: 'someId',
        requestTime: '12/May/2019:12:05:51 +0000',
        path: 'somePath',
        accountId: 'someId',
        protocol: 'HTTP/1.1',
        stage: 'dev',
        domainPrefix: 'someAPIDomain',
        requestTimeEpoch: 1557662751493,
        requestId: 'someId',
        identity: {
            cognitoIdentityPoolId: null,
            accountId: null,
            cognitoIdentityId: null,
            caller: null,
            sourceIp: 'someIP',
            principalOrgId: null,
            accessKey: null,
            cognitoAuthenticationType: null,
            cognitoAuthenticationProvider: null,
            userArn: null,
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/someIP Safari/537.36',
            user: null
        },
        domainName: 'someAPI.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
        apiId: 'someId'
    }
}
```

I am using the default, `Method Request Passthrough` -

```
##  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html
##  This template will pass through all parameters including path, querystring, header, stage variables, and context through to the integration endpoint via the body/payload
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : $input.json('$'),
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"stage-variables" : {
#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
"$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was able to receive the values on the Business Lambda function,
 
by modifying the **Mapping Template, under the API's Integration Request** -

```
"context" : {
    .
    .
    .
    myKey : $context.authorizer.key,
    myNum : $context.authorizer.number,
    myBool : $context.authorizer.bool
}
```

Data was received under event.context object on the function as `myKey, myNum and myBool`.
For those using API Gateway's Integration Request's Lambda Proxy setting, 
don't need to anything, values set on context in the Authorizer function get passed directly.
And should receive under -

```
event.requestContext.authorizer
```